# In the TV show Earth 2, did the colonists actually refer to the planet as "Earth 2"?

Tags: earth-2

As above, I'm wondering if the characters on the show "Earth 2" from the 1990s ever actually referred to their new planet as "Earth 2", or if that was just a catchy title?

Comment: Upvoting because you reminded me of that old show. Sweet memories. ^^

Comment: The planet was [officially] named G889 (I would speculate it was destined to be named Eden, after the colony ship/project), and the colony site was named New Pacifica. Or do you mean colloquially?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A quick scan through the [show transcripts](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/episode_scripts.php?tv-show=earth-2-1994) shows that they didn't refer to it as "*Earth Two*" (in-universe) at any point and that the planet in question is always referred to by its correct name, ***G889***.

> *"We're here to settle this planet."*
>
> ***"Which planet? G889."***
>
> <sup><sub>[Earth Two: All About Eve](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=earth-2-1994&episode=s01e20)</sub></sup>

and

> *"Martin, I assume you have no idea what your friends on level six have planned for us tomorrow."*
>
> ***"Well, they're releasing us to planet G889."***
>
> <sup><sub>[Earth Two: First Contact](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=earth-2-1994&episode=s01e01)</sub></sup>

---

That being said, graffiti and tattoos are seen with the words "E2" on them

> We—” Her voice died in her throat as an image formed on the chamber
> floor at their feet, a design emerging out of the hard-packed earth.
> For a moment it was confusing, like a swirl of graffiti, but then it
> became chillingly clear: “E2.” Completely confounded, she stared in
> amazement as dirt poured away from the design, leaving it clean and
> precise against the background.
>
> <sub><sup>Earth 2: Official Novelisation</sup></sub>

with the implication that certain minority groups view this planet as "*Earth 2*" (or possibly "*Eden 2*")

---

Alternative likely contenders for eventual renaming would presumably include *Eden* or *New Eden* (after the '*Eden Project*')

> *"**G889 was supposed to have been Eden.** Uninhabited, ready for the taking."*
>
> <sup><sub>[Earth Two: Better Living Through Morganite](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=earth-2-1994&episode=s01e13)</sub></sup>